# Handling difference between strings returned in history change handler

Tags: firefox, gwt, google-chrome, urldecode

I've got an app that receives urls after the # sign and responds to them with a History `ValueChangeHandler`.  Serious problem: the urls are escaped differently on different browsers.

For example, when I go to #riley%2Blark%40gmail.com, Chrome sends my ValueChangeHandler `riley%2Blark%40gmail.com` while FireFox sends `riley+lark@gmail.com`.  This is a terrible difference if I want to run `URL.decodeQueryString` on them because I'll end up with an extra space in Firefox.

How can I handle this, short of writing separate implementations for different browsers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of two possible solutions:

1. U could try adding another parameter
   to the token so that the token was
   of the for 
   `#riley%2Blark%40gmail.com/%2B-a-space`
   on receiving the token, check the
   second part of the token. If the
   second part contains a %2B,
   urldecode the token. else replace '+' with
2. You can also try using `Location.hash`
   through JSNI. I reckon the results
   ought to be uniform.

Comment: Great ideas.  Unfortunately #2 fails - it returns different strings.  Firefox is just determined to pre-urldecode the hash, I guess.